# GeoTools reprojecting SimpleFeatureCollection return invalid datatypes

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools

Hard to wrap the question into a title. I build a custom ReprojectionClass today to transform a whole SimpleFeatureCollection into a different CRS (currently hard coded to EPSG:3857

The transformation part works very well. But somehow there is an error I guess. I wrapped this class into a WPS Process to test it and I got back invalid data-types. When I want to get the result as json for example I can see the transformed geometries. The values are correct but it seems like the geometry just gets printed into the attribute table..?

Could you take a look at my code whether this is the correct way to create a SimpleFeatureCollection?
(code mainly taken from Ian Turton and the GeoTools help)

```
import java.util.List;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureIterator;
import org.geotools.feature.DefaultFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureBuilder;
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTS;
import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;
import org.opengis.feature.type.AttributeDescriptor;
import org.opengis.feature.type.AttributeType;
import org.opengis.feature.type.GeometryType;
import org.opengis.geometry.MismatchedDimensionException;
import org.opengis.geometry.coordinate.Polygon;
import org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException;
import org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException;
import org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem;
import org.opengis.referencing.operation.MathTransform;
import org.opengis.referencing.operation.TransformException;

public class ReprojectFeatureClass {

    public ReprojectFeatureClass() {

    }

    public SimpleFeatureCollection reprojectCollection(SimpleFeatureCollection input) {

        DefaultFeatureCollection featureCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection();
        CoordinateReferenceSystem newCRS;
        CoordinateReferenceSystem oldCRS = input.getSchema().getCoordinateReferenceSystem();

        try {


            newCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:3857", true);
            MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(oldCRS, newCRS);


            SimpleFeatureIterator transformationIterator = input.features();
            SimpleFeature feature = null;

            while (transformationIterator.hasNext()) {
                feature = transformationIterator.next();
                Geometry to_transform = (Geometry) feature.getDefaultGeometry();

                // written by Ian Turton
                // https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298451/creating-buffer-around-features-using-geotools

                SimpleFeatureType schema = feature.getFeatureType();
                SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder ftBuilder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
                ftBuilder.setCRS(newCRS);

                for (AttributeDescriptor attrib : schema.getAttributeDescriptors()) {
                    AttributeType type = attrib.getType();

                    if (type instanceof GeometryType) {
                      String oldGeomAttrib = attrib.getLocalName();
                      ftBuilder.add(oldGeomAttrib, Polygon.class);
                    } else {
                      ftBuilder.add(attrib);
                    }
                }
                ftBuilder.setName(schema.getName());

                SimpleFeatureType nSchema = ftBuilder.buildFeatureType();
                SimpleFeatureBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(nSchema);
                List<Object> atts = feature.getAttributes();
                for (int i = 0; i < atts.size(); i++) {
                  if (atts.get(i) instanceof Geometry) {
                      Geometry transformedGeometry = JTS.transform(((Geometry) to_transform), transform); // transformation takes part here
                      atts.set(i, transformedGeometry);
                  }
                }

                SimpleFeature nFeature = builder.buildFeature(null, atts.toArray());
                featureCollection.add(nFeature);


            }


        } catch (NoSuchAuthorityCodeException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FactoryException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MismatchedDimensionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Geometry transformedGeometry = JTS.transform(((Geometry) value), transform);

        return featureCollection;
    }
}
```

Edit:

Here is an example input:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "jsonm",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 0 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 10.130721990327313, 51.608634889408897 ], [ 10.201811051897559, 51.608634889408897 ], [ 10.15313049886576, 51.536773120647673 ], [ 10.100586409879055, 51.573863065814756 ], [ 10.130721990327313, 51.608634889408897 ] ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

and this is the output:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"the_geom":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[1127746.8133,6729668.6238],[1135660.4115,6729668.6238],[1130241.3171,6716797.5915],[1124392.1359,6723438.1641],[1127746.8133,6729668.6238]]]]},"id":0},"id":"fid--46629d12_168db8ecc87_-7fff"}]}
```

The input was imported to GeoServer as Shapefile. The json variant here is just a quick conversion made by QGIS (to post it here).

If I transform the original file to EPSG:3857 in QGIS and save the result as GeoJSON I can see that the calculated coordinates match exactly. Just the way the json is build by the WPS process is misformated I guess ...?

Comment: can you add some example input and output?

Comment: Ok I added my test data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you don't set the default geometry, if you compare your code to [`FeatureTypes.transform()`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/feature/FeatureTypes.java#L200) that seems to be the only obvious difference.

```
/**
 * Forces the specified CRS on geometry attributes (all or some, depends on the parameters).
 *
 * @param schema the original schema
 * @param crs the forced crs
 * @param forceOnlyMissing if true, will force the specified crs only on the attributes that do
 *     miss one
 * @return
 * @throws SchemaException
 */
public static SimpleFeatureType transform(
        SimpleFeatureType schema, CoordinateReferenceSystem crs, boolean forceOnlyMissing)
        throws SchemaException {
    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder tb = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
    tb.setName(schema.getTypeName());
    tb.setNamespaceURI(schema.getName().getNamespaceURI());
    tb.setAbstract(schema.isAbstract());

    GeometryDescriptor defaultGeometryType = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < schema.getAttributeCount(); i++) {
        AttributeDescriptor attributeType = schema.getDescriptor(i);
        if (attributeType instanceof GeometryDescriptor) {
            GeometryDescriptor geometryType = (GeometryDescriptor) attributeType;
            AttributeDescriptor forced;

            tb.descriptor(geometryType);
            if (!forceOnlyMissing || geometryType.getCoordinateReferenceSystem() == null) {
                tb.crs(crs);
            }

            tb.add(geometryType.getLocalName(), geometryType.getType().getBinding());
        } else {
            tb.add(attributeType);
        }
    }
    if (schema.getGeometryDescriptor() != null) {
        tb.setDefaultGeometry(schema.getGeometryDescriptor().getLocalName());
    }

    tb.setSuperType((SimpleFeatureType) schema.getSuper());

    return tb.buildFeatureType();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code example. I copied the setDefaultGeometry part into my code and now the generated json works fine. The creation of a shapefile as output still fails though. Strange thing, right? But nevertheless, when my generated SimpleFeatureCollection seems to be ok now I should be able to work on with that in memory. No need for me to generate a Shapefile as output ..

Comment: Ok, changing the import from org.opengis.geometry.coordinate.Polygon; to org.opengis.geometry.coordinate.Polygon; solved that problem

Comment: After further testing with more complex data I must say that it is still not working properly.The method creates sometimes invalid geometries ...

Comment: there is no general method to go from 4326 to 3857 with out some geometries ending up as invalid (anything +/-85 latitude for example).

Comment: Yes that might be true but those polygons get destroyed totally so that they are no longer closed for example. QGIS transformes those geometries perfectly. But anyway I will not use this code so there is no need for me to figure this out. This was just an answer to my prvious problem here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307957/geotools-correct-use-of-reprojectingfeaturecollection#
But I have this problem figured out now. I will post an answer there soon. Thank you aggain for your help and all the effort you provide here at stackexchange! Your code examples always help me.